# Does the Prowler's spinning boomerang attack use ranged attack values?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

The Prowler has an attack that is, in my opinion, not entirely clear on whether it counts as a melee or ranged attack.

After throwing two boomerangs, pressing A again will cause the Prowler to rush forward while holding a boomerang in its paw and spinning, dealing several hits. Is the damage for this attack calculated using the weapon's melee attack value or ranged attack value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/-JkNVpbfJKI?t=5m20s), the damage is actually part melee and part ranged, specifically 26 motion value for the melee damage, and 8 motion value for the ranged damage.